# DPM for File Server - awfully slow?

Tags: system-center, scdpm

Testing DPM 2016 now. I find it awfully slow for working on a file server (a million files, around 5tb of data - so something quite small). It looks like DPM is copying the files one by one to a vhdx in the backup area.

Anyone has any idea about standard procedures to speed this up? Right now I am seriously on the side that I will virtualize the file server and move that to a fully virtual infrastructure (i.e. only the infrastructure has hardware) because I can pull a backup of a VM with full wire speed - contrary to the file server.

I did some searching on the internet, and I find a lot of references to this issue going back many years. Examples:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe5020e1-2ca3-44a5-85c0-acd65508f08a/dpm-2012-slow-file-backup?forum=dataprotectionmanager

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/420872-system-center-2012-dpm-slow-replica-creation

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff9b8081-68dd-4c0f-8fd4-7b23950c4f20/consistency-check-takes-forever-on-large-volumes?forum=dpmfilebackup

and nothing seems to have changed in the 2016 version?

Comment: Have you checked the similar "issue" : [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/843249ab-ba6e-4eba-84ff-cfa769f31a0e/dpm-2016-file-server-backup-slow?forum=dpmfilebackup)

Comment: Yes. Not using dedup here - and it still is slow as molass. I think we will fully virtualize storage and then pull a backup on the VM.

Comment: Based on this , if there is no performance issue on that server ,  I'm afraid virtualizing that file server then backup VM is better than backup folder .